# Loop Get-VM Powershell

Tags: powershell

Im looking for a for a Script, that get-vm * and then goes to "sleep" for 5 seconds, and then get-vm Again.

so far ive came up with this:

```
cls
get-vm *
Start-Sleep 5
```

But then it only writes it one time.

What is the right code to get it going in loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an endless loop:

```
while ($true)
{
  cls 
  Write-Host "Getting VMs at $(get-date)"
  get-vm * 
  Start-Sleep 5
}
```

Use Ctrl+C to end the loop.

Comment: Hello. Powershell is accepting the Script, but is not giving any output?

Comment: Added a Write-Host to verify it's running. If it only displays that, then get-vm * isn't returning any results.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? Could you try to make an example please?

Comment: If i write "Get-VM *" in a normal powershell prompt, then it Works fine.

Comment: I updated the posted script. What do you get if you run that?

Comment: Then i get the date, and nothing else. But the date keeps updating so the loop is working fine :)

Comment: Im using Powershell ISE

Comment: I don't have an explanation for that.

Comment: :( - Anyway thx for your help :) Hope that someone else knows why :)

Comment: @user277682 are you trying to do this loop within a function?

Comment: Yes (i assume - new to coding). But if inside {} then its a funtion based on the "while argument" right?

Comment: @user277682 can you post more of your script with the modifications you made?

Comment: The script is exactly is the one above - i have tried to modify it, but didnt change anything :(

Comment: Add `Import-Module Hyper-V` to the top of the script(before while-loop). The script above should work.